# I have a timecodes list how to update my records with those timecodes using update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash, update-attributes

Voilà I have a list like this 0, 1000, 2860, 3619, 4789, 5970 in a field of my database. I would like to iterate over it and update the corresponding subtitle with the value of the timecode.

Here is my code. It is all in a view:

```
          <%if params[:envoi]%>

            <%@ze_videos.each do |attached| %>
                <h1><%= attached.remarque %></h1>
                <% @mesattachedtcs = attached.remarque %>
            <%end%>
            <p> 

                <% @tchash = "" %>
                <% @mesattachedtcs.split(/, ?/).each do |montc| %>
                        <% @tchash = @tchash + '"' + montc.to_s + '"' + ', ' %> 
                <%end%>
                <%# @tchash = '{' + @tchash + '}' %>

                <%= @tchash %>
                <% aa = 0 %>
                <% @traductions.each do |sync| %>
                    <% aa += 1 %>
                    <%= @tchash[aa] %> _
                    <%  
                        @temps = (@tchash[aa]).to_i          
                        if sync.auteur == current_user.email 
                            sync.update_attributes(:timecode => @temps)
                        end
                    %>

                <%end%>
            </p>



        <%end%>
```

What I do not understand is that <%= @tchash[aa] %> is not a being saved with the corresponding subtitle. But the value goes in the database in a "cryptographic" way.
Like this [image]

I'm not a pro with hashes, it works very fine if I write the hash in the code: myhash = [111, 222, 333, 444] and access the value or the key with myHash[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVtuw.jpg), myHash[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB5mJ.png)..

In this pict you see that I have not a whole variable but each character of the string is dispatched in the column Timecode instead of being in one row.
[image]
Could you please help me in this matter? Merci

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I just didn't look at the theory. I had to say Hash.new() before all.